# Downloading File with with special characters in file name

Tags: java

I cannot download file using java if the url contains special characters.

eg:-http://something.com/something/this+this+this.html

http://something.com/something/this%20this%20this.html

the same happens if i download the file using google chrome...

I am developing a downloader in java.. please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UrlEncoder.Encode(...)
Java Methos ,
hope this will help you

and use decoder at client side

Comment: thank you yogesh. the best method is when we can convert filename using the following code

filename=URLDecoder.decode(filename,"UTF-8");